# Can't list all the root folders in my bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I have a bucket, in which there are about 2500 folders. Each folder has some files.
Looks like:

```
test1/xxxxxx.jpg
test1/yyyy.jpg
test1/.....
..
..
test1/zzzz.jpg
test2/sdfdsf.jpg
....
test2500/dsfds.jpg
```

I want to list all the folders (I expect to get an array-like of the folders: `[test1, test2, ..., ..., test2500]`.

This is my code:

```
const s3 = require('s3');

const client = s3.createClient({
    s3Options: {
        accessKeyId: 'myKEY',
        secretAccessKey: 'myKEY',
        region: 'myREGION'
    }
});

const directoriesEmitter = client.listObjects({
    s3Params: {
        Bucket: 'BUCKET',
        Delimiter: '/',
        Prefix: '',
    },
    recursive: false
});

let s3imagesDirNames;

directoriesEmitter.on('data', (data) => {
    s3imagesDirNames = data;
});

directoriesEmitter.on('end', () => {
    console.log(s3imagesDirNames);
});
```

When I print it I only get 269 folders (Maximum is 100 tho).

The result is in the `CommonPrefixes`.

Answer (score 2):

The SDK returns at most 1000 results. If results are paginated, then you need to re-issue the list call with a continuation token. See `IsTruncated` and `NextContinuationToken` in the response, and `ContinuationToken` in the request.

Also, you should use `listObjectsV2` rather than the deprecated `listObjects`.